# What is the type of a Java empty Optional?

Tags: java, option-type

So the thing is I was checking `Optional` Java class and I noticed this in the `public static<T> Optional<T> empty()` doc:

```
@param <T> The type of the non-existent value*.
```

And, after looking at the whole class and searching over here and a few other pages I came to this questions that I haven't been able to answer:

1. Can an empty `Optional` have a specific type?
   1.1 If so, how do you set it?
   1.2 And is there any way to check its type?

Comment: The generic type parameter doesn't exist at runtime. So the type of the empty Optional object is just `Optional`. When you require an empty `Optional<T>`, the compiler can assume whatever generic type `T` is requires for the context; and it doesn't cause a problem because there's no object inside it to be of the wrong type.

Comment: type interference from where you what to store/assign

Comment: @Eklavya but what if I do not store it? The whole _type of the non-existent value_ makes it confusing for me.

Comment: Consider it vague like `(T) null` (though _not_ null). The reason that `empty()` is a function and not a class constant is that you then have a typed `Optional<T>` value.

Comment: I think you want to research Java generics in the first place. There is nothing different about Optional that you wouldnt find in other generic classes ...

Comment: It’s not different to `List<String> list1 = Collections.emptyList(); List<Integer> list2 = Collections.emptyList();` The type of the lists is only determined by their referencing variables. That’s why, perhaps surprisingly, `list1 == (Object)list2` will be `true`. Same for `Function<String,String> f1 = Function.identity(); Function<Integer,Integer> f2 = Function.identity();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Optional` class is a container that might contain a specific element. As such, it has two concepts:

- The type it might contain
- The actual object it contains

The type it might contain is specified trough generics. Generics only exist at compile time and are lost at runtime.

To answer your questions:

1. When using an `Optional`, you usually define it to possibly contain a type, like this:

```
Optional<String> optionalString;
```

At this point we know that `optionalString` *might* contain a String. If we do this:

```
Optional<String> optionalString = Optional.empty();
```

It doesn't actually contain anything, but we can use it anywhere an `Optional<String>` is required.

2. The type of the `Optional` is inferred trough its usage. Like above, you specify the `Optional.empty()` to be an `Optional<String>`. You can also specify its type trough the return value of a method, like so:

```
public Optional<Integer> findNumber() {
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

3. Since the type is no longer present at runtime, there is no way to check what the optional contains at this point. At runtime, an empty `Optional` has no type.

Comment: You can create and empty with a specific type using: Optional.<String>empty();

Answer (score 10):

It's whatever type you specify:

```java
// Empty Optional with value type String
Optional<String> opt = Optional.empty();
```

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java) for that method from OpenJDK 11:

```java
    public static<T> Optional<T> empty() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Optional<T> t = (Optional<T>) EMPTY;
        return t;
    }
```

`EMPTY` is a static instance (from the source code linked above):

```java
    /**
     * Common instance for {@code empty()}.
     */
    private static final Optional<?> EMPTY = new Optional<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know a Link to a Blogpost has already been posted, but I always refer back to this on: [Baeldung Java Optional 8](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional)

To ur questions:

1. Optional can contain any Object type(if u need an int then use Integer)
2. `Optional.of(urObject)` now the "type" is Optional
3. No u can't check the type of the Optional.